# Test of an if path not working in angular/jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am truing to write a test a path that exists in an ngOnInit function.  And I thought I had found the way to do it looking at stackoverflow. The code of the function is:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.partNoKey = params.get('partNoKey');
      this.from = params.get('from');
     // console.log(this.partNoKey);
     // console.log(this.from);

      if(this.from=="ncCutterSheetEdit"){
        this.fromCutterSheet=true;
      }
    });
```

what I have as my test case currently is:

```
  it('should set fromCutterSheet to true when from is ncCutterSheetEdit', () =>{
    component.from = "ncCutterSheetEdit";
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.from).toContain('ncCutterSheetEdit');
    expect(component.fromCutterSheet).toBeTrue();
  })
```

if I comment out the last expect statement the test passes, but when I un-comment that expect statement it fails with the error "Expected false to be true."

Also after writing the test case when I look coverage report it is still showing the if statement as being a path not taken. I am guessing I don't have the right example for what I want to do.

Can someone please point me to a more appropriate example for this test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngOninit` runs after calling the first `detectChanges` after `TestBed.createComponent(...)`. You need to mock `ActivatedRoute` before that and particularly the `paramMap` aspect of it. I suspect it never goes into your `subscribe` block.

Something like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
  //.....
  providers: [.... 
              {
                 provide: ActivatedRoute, 
                 useValue: { paramMap: of({ partNoKey: 'hello', from: 'noCutterSheetEdit' })
               }],
```

An answer that can give you further details and allow you to control: [How to test ngrx store action dispatch on route params change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153954/how-to-test-ngrx-store-action-dispatch-on-route-params-change/60168817#60168817)

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed

Comment: Actually I already had an activated route in the before each, hence before the code report was showing the else path was taken.

Comment: Doing tests of what goes on in `ngOnInit` can be difficult because the first `detectChanges` makes it run, you have to be creative with `beforeEach`, and `describe` blocks. And unfortunately can result in repeated code.

Comment: While repeating code is not ideal, I can get to the point were both paths are tested anyway.